# How do I properly subclass a "dict"?

Tags: python, oop

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        #fill in here
```

How do I write the constructor so that it sets the key '`name`' to '`james`'.

```
d = MyDict()
print d['name'] ....this should print out "james"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (C)Python 2.5.2:

```
>>> class MyDict(dict):
...   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...     super(MyDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
...     self['name'] = 'james'
...
>>> d = MyDict()
>>> print d['name']
james
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic subclass of dict will allow basic storage:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self['name'] = 'james'
```

For more complicated storage, you may want to look into [__setitem__](http://diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/special_class_methods.html) and [__getitem__](http://diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/special_class_methods.html)

Comment: should I always do "super(MyDict,self)..." in the constructor everytime I want to subclass a dict? Is it a requirement?

Comment: dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) would also work, but the super() style is recommended.

Comment: If you don't call dict's __init__ at all, then your object may not have a consistent state and may therefore not be usable as a dict would be.

Comment: @wberry, @TIMEX: super() style is required for multiple inheritance to work.